# Need help solving a PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE to solve:
$$
f_{xx}(x,y) - \tfrac{y^2}{c^2} f(x,y) = -\tfrac{\alpha y}{c^2}x,\quad 0<x<a,\quad y>0,
$$
with boundary conditions:
$$
f(0,y)=f_x(a,y)=0.
$$

Since the only derivative is in $x$, we take $y$ as a constant, treating this as a system of ODEs.
By solving the homogeneous equation (i.e., $f_{xx}-\tfrac{y^2}{c^2}f=0$), and then the inhomogeneous equation (using the particular solution $f=px$), I achieved the solution:
$$
f(x,y)=Ae^{yx/c}+Be^{-yx/c} + \tfrac \alpha yx,
$$
where $\frac \alpha y=p$.

However, unless I am mistaken, the boundary conditions don’t seem to be enough information to determine the value of these constants. Is my solution incorrect, or am I missing something more obvious?

Comment: Your attempt looks good to me. You can deduce that $A=-B$ from initial condition

Comment: The solution form is correct, but it's important to realize that $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary functions of $y$, without more boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct.
$$f(x,y)=A(y)e^{yx/c}+B(y)e^{-yx/c} + \dfrac \alpha yx,$$
Then you deduce that $A=-B$ from
$$f(0,y)=0$$
And continue with the second initial condition, you should get $A(y)$ as a function of $\cosh$ function. 
$$f_x(a,y)=0$$
$$A(y)(e^{ya/c}+e^{-ya/c}) =- \dfrac {c \alpha}{y^2}$$
$$A(y)\cosh ({ya/c}) =- \dfrac {c \alpha}{2y^2}$$
Finally:
$$A(y) =-B(y)=- \dfrac {c \alpha}{2y^2\cosh ({ya/c})}$$

$$f(x,y)=- \dfrac {c \alpha \sinh ({yx/c})}{y^2\cosh ({ya/c})} + \dfrac \alpha yx,$$

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I hadn’t considered $A$ and $B$ as functions of $y$, rather than just constants.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a PDE so the constants are functions of the variable y @user87938971.

Comment: All what you did is correct. @user87938971